# Modifying internal-border-width messes up UI

Tags: frames

When I am modifying the `internal-border-width` of the selected frame the "resizing" happens but for example the minibuffer and the modeline are not visible anymore. They are there but offscreen:[image: unbalanced emacs borders]

As you can see the borders are unbalanced and the buffer is "pushed" from the top left.

This is likely to be window manager related (bspwm in my case). Because when I for example full screen emacs after setting the internal border width everything looks as expected. Same when I open another application or anything like that which "repositions" and that causes a "redraw":

[image: after repositioning]

Can this be solved from within my .emacs.d or do I need to look in my window manager or somewhere else?

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe from `emacs -Q`, stating your Emacs build (`M-x emacs-version`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: If you modify certain aspects of Emacs geometry (in my case `internal-border-width` and it does not seem to be respected by the window system, try putting your settings also in `.Xdefaults` or `.Xresources` (I think the latter is preferred nowadays).

See this link for more on this http://www.linux-france.org/article/appli/emacs/manuel/html/resources-x.html